# Customize like message on facebook activity log

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-like

How to customize the facebook like message that appears on the users activity log after he likes using the like button. I've seen this customization for Wordpress.com
Whenever someone likes the wordpress.com website the log appears like this

[image: Facebook like message for wordpress.com]

here there's the additional text "on Wordpress.com". The like symbol on left is also customized to wordpress image.

How to achieve this customization on facebook using open graph tags ??

Answer (score 0):

Just add this to your html head

```
<meta content='Your website name' property='og:site_name'>
```

To get 'Your website name' to the end.

The icon is added by a dedicated FB Application ( http://developers.facebook.com ). Just create an app for your website and add the icon to the 'App Details' of your app. Also add the Facebook SDK to your website!